# Precalculus: Analyzing Graphs: Homework

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis

So this is the homework for my precalculus class. It’s usually fine — I end up teaching myself the relevant content because it is difficult to understand the teacher and the other students waste a lot of the class time on irrelevant information. However, this time, the instructor has failed to go over problems similar to the following two (2), and so I was not sure regarding the correct completion of these problems.

Images included below:
[image: Problem 1]

As I said, the instructor did not explicitly cover problems similar to these, so I was unsure of how to solve them. I consulted the book and *some* online materials, but could not find anything specifically relevant to problem resolution in these cases. 
[image: Problem 2]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $x$ can get arbitrarily small and arbitrarily large, provided that you extend the curve far enough. Likewise, $y$ can get arbitrarily large. So the domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$ and the range is $[-4, \infty)$.

To find the zeroes of a rational function, just set the numerator equal to zero, solve for $x$, and check that the zero is in the domain of the function. Indeed, the only zero of $\frac{x}{49x^2 - 81}$ is $x = 0$.

Comment: According to the software, the first solution Domain: $(-\infty, \infty)$, Range: $[-4, \infty)$; is incorrect. I’m not sure what they’re looking for and that’s where my problem is stemming from, I think.

Comment: Is the software called WebAssign?

Comment: @PaulSundheim: Indeed, it is WebAssign.